# Probability of picking the red marble twice

Tags: mathematics

Start with a bag containing one red marble and one white marble.

- Reach into the bag and pull out a marble at random.
- Put it back and do it again.
- If, on both times, you grabbed the red marble, stop.
- Otherwise add two white marbles to the bag and repeat these steps.

> What is the probability you eventually grab the red marble twice during an iteration?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The probability

> that you *never* draw the red marble twice in a row is the probability that you don't on the first iteration, times the probability that after that you don't on the second iteration, times the probability that after *that* you don't on the third iteration, and so forth.

That equals

> $\frac34\cdot\frac{15}{16}\cdot\frac{35}{36}\cdot\frac{63}{64}\cdots$ or $\frac{1\cdot3}{2\cdot2}\cdot\frac{3\cdot5}{4\cdot4}\cdot\frac{5\cdot7}{6\cdot6}\cdot\frac{7\cdot9}{8\cdot8}\cdots$.

This is exactly

> the reciprocal of the famous Wallis product for $\pi$, so the probability of *never* getting a red pair is $\frac2\pi$ and the probability of *ever* getting one is therefore $1-\frac2\pi$ or about 36.34%.

Comment: Aye, there's my problem. I knew I was missing something.

Answer (score 1):

The value is equivalent to an infinite series according to the function:

> SUM(n=1,inf,(1/2n)^2)

Equivalent to:

> (1/4)SUM(n=1,inf,1/n^2)

Which the latter returns:

> pi^2/6, divided by 4 gives us pi^2/24, or roughly 41.1%. It definitely feels odd that in this case it is more likely that this procedure will continue infinitely than it is that it would eventually end. Very interesting problem!

Comment: Good try, but the actual answer is even lower.

Comment: What's the reasoning and the mistake in this answer? (Assuming the other answer is right, which I think it is)

Comment: The answer didn’t account that by going with this approach, it’s an XOR problem not an OR problem.